# Como selecionar os ids de uma tabela com checkbox e salvar no banco?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Como selecionar alguns itens de uma tabela dimanica vinda do banco de dados mysql e carregada em uma tabela usando javascript ou jquery e setar as marcadas com checkbox a categoria como 'esporte' no banco de dados?
abaixo tem um esboço do código

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Categoria</th>
        <th>Editar</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $id ?>" value="<?php echo $id ?>"></td>
        <td>Fifa 2017</td>
        <td>Não definido</td>
        <td><button name="Editar">Editar</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $id ?>" value="<?php echo $id ?>"></td>
        <td>Formula 1</td>
        <td>não definido</td>
        <td><button name="Editar">Editar</button></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

No exemplo acima quero selecionar os dois ítens e editar os mesmos para que a categoria seja esporte.

Penso em recuperar os ids dos checkbox selecionados e gravar em um Array() e depois pegar este Array() e fazer update no banco com os dados.

Preciso selecionar vários e editar apenas 1 vez e não linha a linha.

Comment: Está meio confuso entender.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo vou tentar explicar melhor, eu quero selecionar algumas linhas de uma tabela que pertençam a uma mesma categoria e ao clicar em algum botão abrir uma janela com um input para colocar o nome da categoria e salvar na coluna categoria das linhas selecionadas, ao invés de editar item por item

Comment: Vamos ver se é como entendi seu propósito, marco Fifa 2017 e marco também Formula 1. Clico em um dos dois botões "Editar" para abrir, por exemplo, uma janela flutuante com um input, coloca o nome da categoria e salvar na coluna categoria. Pode me dizer que coluna categoria é essa?

Comment: perfeito exatamente isto, essa coluna categoria é no banco de dados, não ficará visível na tabela html em questão, eu fiz uma flutuante para salvar mas só consigo fazer linha a linha, mas agora me deparei em uma situação que a informação de várias linhas é a mesma por isso penso em ter um jeito de editar várias de uma unica forma

Comment: pois é, os ids e os values dos inputs são os mesmos. Vale lembrar que IDs são únicos. Cada elemento pode ter apenas um ID. Cada página pode ter apenas um elemento com aquele ID. Seu código não vai passar pelo validador se você usar o mesmo ID em mais de um elemento.

Comment: o id do input está dinamico, ele traz o id do banco dados, correspondente a cada linha.

Comment: tinha esquecido desse detalhe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você assim para coletar os **IDs** que deseja alterar, depois envia o novo **array** com IDs para seu PHP salva no banco.

```js
function coletaDados(){
   var ids = document.getElementsByClassName('editar');
   coletaIDs(ids);         
}  
        
function coletaIDs(dados){
   var array_dados = dados; 
   var newArray = [];
   for(var x = 0; x <= array_dados.length; x++){     
        if(typeof array_dados[x] == 'object'){
          if(array_dados[x].checked){
             newArray.push(array_dados[x].id)          
          }          
        }
   }
  if(newArray.length <= 0){
    alert("Selecione um pelo menos 1 item!");     
  }else{
    alert("Seu novo array de IDs tem os seguites ids [ "+newArray+" ]");
  }  
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Categoria</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" id="01" value="Fifa"></td>
        <td>Fifa 2017</td>
        <td>Não definido</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" id="02" value="Formula 1"></td>
        <td>Formula 1</td>
        <td>não definido</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <button style="width:100%;" onclick="coletaDados()">Editar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: agradeço a atenção e era exatamente a minha necessidade.