# Como passar um Array de Javascript para PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Como passar o Array `newArray` de Javascript para um vetor em PHP? A idéia é pegar o valor `id` de cada checkbox e colocar em um vetor em PHP para que esses id's sejam tratados em um banco de dados (como chave primária). [Esse código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202091/como-selecionar-os-ids-de-uma-tabela-com-checkbox-e-salvar-no-banco) já pega os id's dos checkbox's marcados e mostra-os em uma janela.

---

Exemplo:

IDcheckbox: 1, 2, 3

VetorPHP: [1,2,3]

---

```js
function coletaDados() {
  var ids = document.getElementsByClassName('editar');
  coletaIDs(ids);
}

function coletaIDs(dados) {
  var array_dados = dados;
  var newArray = [];
  for (var x = 0; x <= array_dados.length; x++) {
    if (typeof array_dados[x] == 'object') {
      if (array_dados[x].checked) {
        newArray.push(array_dados[x].id)
      }
    }
  }
  if (newArray.length <= 0) {
    alert("Selecione um pelo menos 1 item!");
  } else {
    alert("Seu novo array de IDs tem os seguites ids [ " + newArray + " ]");
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Categoria</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" id="01" value="Barco"></td>
      <td>Barco</td>
      <td>Não definido</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="editar" type="checkbox" id="02" value="Carro"></td>
      <td>Carro</td>
      <td>não definido</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <button style="width:100%;" onclick="coletaDados()">Editar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Além de parecer duplicada, a sua pergunta está meio vaga. Você apenas mostrou o código, mas não deu muitos detalhes do que pretende fazer.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, foi editada a pergunta. Está mais clara agora?

Comment: Agora tá filé..

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você possa usar jQuery e um formulário não é uma opção, você pode tentar o método Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
url: '/caminho/do/seu/script.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'JSON',
data: newArray,
success:function(e){
    console.log(e);
},
error:function(error){
    console.log(error);
}});
```

Ao receber esses dados no PHP ele depende inteiramente de como a array foi montada no javascript.

No Ajax o parametro `DataType` diz qual tipo de dado será retornado na requisição, então seu PHP deverá devolver um JSON, no caso do meu exemplo.  E em `data` você passará o que deseja enviar no POST.

Comment: Fala Felipe. Legal. Mas o que contém no campo `url`? Também, esse código pode ser utilizado na mesma página que contém o código JavaSript?

Comment: Na `url` você deve passar a url para o seu php que vai receber a array.
Ajax é um metodo do jQuery, que por sua vez precisa ser feito em javascript.

Comment: Então pode colocar esse código (AJAX) entre a tag `<script>` `</script>` no arquivo em HTML?

Comment: Contanto que o jquery já esteja carregado, pode.